# Getting 404 while Adding CodeDeploy agent in AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

I was trying to add CodeDeploy agent in my lunux EC2 Instance. But failing in this step.
S3 Bucket name : hukbuk
Region : US East (N. Virginia)  us-east-1

wget https://hukbuk.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install

[image]

Have opended up all permissions for S3 bucket and made it public but still getting the 404 error. should I need to add any file in S3 for adding CodeDeploy agent ?